# Error:(29, 13) Failed to resolve: com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2

Tags: android, gradle

In android studio, Gradle project is failing to sync and causing this error.

> Error:(29, 13) Failed to resolve: com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2

Here's my build.gradle (module)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.user.popularmovies"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', 
    {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:preference-v7:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
}
```

and here's my build.gradle (project)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: can you add `--debug` flag to print more info for me?

Comment: where do I add it?

Comment: `./gradlew dependencies --debug`

Comment: @chenrui many thanks, I did that and it gave me a hint of what could be the problem

Comment: cool! glad that it got resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was the Proxy authentication, 
**`File> Settings...> Appearance & Behavior> System Settings> HTTP Proxy`**

Check the image

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check your internet connectivity and make sure gradle offline work is disabled.

**File>Settings>Build,Execution,Deployment>Gradle**

Disable "offline work" checkbox.

Comment: the internet is connected, could it be something related to the proxy?

Comment: maybe, try disabling it and check.